# Prove or Disprove if $a_n$ has 3 partial limits and $b_n$ has 2 partial limits then could it be that $a_n+b_n$ has one limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I think it has to do with $\sin$ and $\cos$ because most of them have three limits but I couldn't find a good example that it is wrong although I think that it is indeed wrong.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by partial limit?

Comment: Partial limits  mean that for each series there are sub-sequences in which every sub-sequence has a limit of its own

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\alpha_0,\alpha_1$, and $\alpha_2$ are distinct real numbers, and $N_0,N_1$, and $N_2$ are infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ such that the subsequence $\langle a_n:n\in N_k\rangle$ of $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\alpha_k$ for $k=0,1,2$. Suppose further that $\langle a_n+b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\alpha$. Then $\langle b_n:n\in N_k\rangle$ converges to $\alpha-\alpha_k$ for $k=0,1,2$, and the sequence $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has (at least) three different sub-sequential limits.

Comment: is this a proof or an example of a situation in which the statement is invalid?

Comment: @shadihelf: This is a proof that if the sum sequence converges, and the $a$ sequence has three subsequential limits, then the $b$ sequence also has three subsequential limits. In other words, the situation described in the title never occurs.